# Order array such that all positive numbers appear first

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

i am writing a code in c# to sort an array, i want all the negative values in the right side and all the positive values in the left side, the should not be in decreasing order

```
namespace SortApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] newInt = new int[] { 5, -2, -1, -4, -20, 6, 7, -14, 15, -16, 8, 9, 10 };
            int size = 12, i= 0;             // or newInt.Length

            for (i = 0; i < newInt.Length; i++)
            {
                if (newInt[i] < 0 && newInt[size] > 0)
                {
                    int temp = newInt[i];
                    newInt[i] = newInt[size];
                    newInt[size] = temp;
                    size--;
                }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < newInt.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(newInt[i]);
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but the output is something like this (-20 is on wrong side):

```
5 10 9 8 -20 6 7 -14 15 -16 -4 -1 -2
```

but the intended output is:

```
5 10 9 8 15 6 7 -14 -20 -16 -4 -1 -2
```

Why is my code not producing my intended output?

Comment: @pst I disagree, they are asking about their specific solution, which is not a total sort but just 'having negatives on the right side'. Searching for sorting algorithms does not solve their problem.

Comment: the intended output was : 
5 10 9 8 15 6 7 -14 -20 -16 -4 -1 -2, 

sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: In your intended output case the ordering is not stable either (15 appears before 6), so, while it is important to understand why the algorithm is incorrect, something like this would work in LINQ: `arr = arr.OrderBy(e => e > 0 ? 0 : 1).ToArray()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution incorrectly decides when to finish the loop. Also, it unconditionally increments `i` in the loop header, and never decrements `size` even when it points to a negative number.

Here is how you fix it:

```
for (i = 0; i < size ; ) {
    if (newInt[i] < 0 && newInt[size] >= 0) {
        int temp = newInt[i];
        newInt[i] = newInt[size];
        newInt[size] = temp;
        size--;
        i++;
        continue;
    }
    if (newInt[i] >= 0) {
        i++;
    }
    if (newInt[size] < 0) {
        size--;
    }
}
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/SCcH19).

You can rewrite this loop using a more readable identifiers for your `left` and `right` pointers, rather than using `i` and `size`. This would make your algorithm look more "symmetric" in the code, to recognize the symmetry in its design:

```
int left = 0, right = newInt.Length-1;
while (left < right) {
    if (newInt[left] < 0 && newInt[right] >= 0) {
        int temp = newInt[left];
        newInt[left] = newInt[right];
        newInt[right] = temp;
        right--;
        left++;
        continue;
    }
    if (newInt[left] >= 0) {
        left++;
    }
    if (newInt[right] < 0) {
        right--;
    }
}
```

Here is [an ideone link to the alternative implementation](http://ideone.com/myAwLp).

Comment: @MustansirSabir You are welcome! If your problem is solved, you may want to accept the answer by clicking the grey outline of the check mark next to it. This would indicate that you are no longer looking for an improved solution to this problem, and earn you a brand-new badge on stack overflow.

Comment: Given the array `{0, -1, 1, 0}`, this will never terminate. You need to decide if `0` is considered positive or negative, and adjust your code accordingly (i.e. `newInt[right] >= 0`).

Comment: @JimMischel That's a good point - thank you very much! This is now fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution:

```
var newInt = new[] {5, -2, -1, -4, -20, 6, 7, -14, 15, -16, 8, 9, 10};
var solution = newInt.GroupBy(i => i > 0).
    SelectMany(g => g).
    ToArray();
```

The problem with your algorithm is that when you decrease `size`, you end up having `newInt[size]` point at a negative value, and the `if` block is not entered.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea for a pretty easy easy solution would be to start one index, call it `left` at the beginning of the array, and another, called `right` at the end of the array.

Increment `left` until you find a negative number, or until `left == right`. When you hit a negative number, decrement `right` until you find a positive number, or until `right == left`.

If `left` is indexing a negative number and `right` is indexing a positive number, swap the two items and start incrementing `left` again.

The general idea, not tested:

```
int left = 0;
int right = a.Length-1;
while (left < right)
{
    if (a[left] < 0)
    {
        while (right > left)
        {
            if (a[right] >= 0)
            {
                // swap here
                int temp = a[left];
                a[left] = a[right];
                a[right] = temp;
                break;
             }
             --right;
        }
    }
    ++left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This yields the desired order with a minimum of loops

```
int[] newInt = new int[] { 5, -2, -1, -4, -20, 6, 7, -14, 15, -16, 8, 9, 10 };
int lt = 0;
int rt = newInt.Length - 1;
while (true) {
    // Find first negative number
    while (newInt[lt] >= 0 && lt < rt) {
        lt++;
    }

    // Find last positive number
    while (newInt[rt] < 0 && rt > lt) {
        rt--;
    }

    if (lt == rt) {
        break; // Finished
    }

    // Swap
    int temp = newInt[lt];
    newInt[lt] = newInt[rt];
    newInt[rt] = temp;
}
//TODO: Print result
```

Comment: Given the array `{0, -1, 1, 0}`, this will never terminate. It will swap the first and last items forever. Is `0` positive or negative?

Comment: You are right. I treated 0 as positive now. Another possibility would to place 0 between positive and negative numbers. But that would require an extra treatment.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use generics and linq than the easiest solution would be :

```
int[] newInt = new int[] { 5, -2, -1, -4, -20, 6, 7, -14, 15, -16, 8, 9, 10 };
newInt.ToList().Sort();
newInt.Reverse();
newInt = newInt.ToArray();
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: The return type of `Sort` is `void`

Comment: OP does not want sorting. He want 2 partitions one each for negative and positive values

Comment: @pst ->  "should not be in decreasing order", and looking at source code logic, He want to shift all nevatives to the right side (without any sorting)

Comment: Kundan i intentionally don't want to sort numbers in any order i just want to place all the negetive values in the right and all the positive values in the left and don't want to use any bult-in functions for this,

your code will definitely work well

Comment: @Tilak Nope, that is not correct and a normal sort *would* achieve the desired results. He/she doesn't care about ordering apparently. See the expected output case.